# Adding related “documents” to a story

Tags: fiction

I’m writing a fiction novel set in the future where a dictator creates an act that sets the laws and punishments of the land. Part of that act, a title of it, is a dress code.

I’m interjecting portions of it into the narrative of the story as different subjects and violations come up, but I’d like to give the readers a look at the entirety of the documents.

Since it’s a bunch of legalese, if I put them at the beginning no one would read past them. So would I be better served to include them somewhere in the middle or attach to the end where after reading the story the reader might think they’d like to read it and it would put the entire “world” in a better perspective?

Each is about a page to page and a half.

Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't read "Watchmen" it's a graphic novel the put much of it's world building lore documents at the end of each installment (As it was originally sold as a multipart comic book series, this would be after the conclusion of each issue's story).   If you placed each Lore Page between the end of each chapter, it could work.  It might be best to pad the work so that, when printed and bound, the back of the last page of the Chapter is left blank, use a front and back for two Lore components, and then start the next chapter on a fresh page.   Alternatively, if the chapter ends on the back of a page, have the front/back lore element followed by the start of the new chapter on the next clean page.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, in *Nineteen Eighty-Four* by George Orwell, the Principles of Newspeak are explained in an Appendix at the end - this could work too.

Comment: Thanks. That’s what I’m thinking might work just to give it a concise explanation.